# ERROR 1241 (21000): Operand should contain 1 column(s) in multiple selects

Tags: mysql

```
   select
        (select sum(sal)as sal_tp, sum(local_conv) as lc_tp from budget_tp),
        (select sum(sal) from budget_fos_veri) as sal_veri,
        (select sum(sal) from budget_fos_picks)as sal_pick,
        (select sum(sal) from budget_bpo_other)as sal_bpo;
```

I get

```
ERROR 1241 (21000): Operand should contain 1 column(s).
```

Is there any way for my requirement to complete? The query is actually a sample. I have many tables with multiple columns, I would like to view the sum of individual columns of all the tables, I just tried to view two at a time in first line I get this error, if I try to retrieve only one column then its fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each subquery should return one field. Try thy query -

```
   select
        (select sum(sal) from budget_tp) as sal_tp,
        (select sum(local_conv) from budget_tp) as lc_tp,
        (select sum(sal) from budget_fos_veri) as sal_veri,
        (select sum(sal) from budget_fos_picks)as sal_pick,
        (select sum(sal) from budget_bpo_other)as sal_bpo;
```

Another one:

```
   select
        (select concat(sum(sal), ',' ,sum(local_conv)) from budget_tp) as sal_tp_and_lc_tp
        (select sum(local_conv) from budget_tp) as lc_tp,
        ...
```

Comment: That is ok, what if each table have 10 cols and I have such 50 tables, that would be 50*10 that is 500 selects??

Comment: It is strange query. You also may do something like this - `select 1 column1, (select concat(2,', ', 3)) as column2and3`. I mean you can use one SELECT for each table, but all fields are selected as one field.

Comment: The problem is I want to get sum of individual column, not the the sum of all cols, I have around 50 tables and each table have multiple column, I just need to view the sum of them. Uh! not able to explain, I think someone got me. :d

Comment: It would be great help if someone explained using the query given in the question.

Comment: Have a look at example. You won't get sum of all columns, you will get sum of individual column in another way.